# How to get data from observablecollection and display into console application in c#?

Tags: c#

How do i get data from observablecollection object and display into console application using c#?

Example:

```
ObservableCollection<classname> object1= method(parameters);
```

Here i need to print data containing in object1.

Comment: Could you clarify what is your problem in particular?
What prevents you to fulfill this task?

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote, but this shows some serious lack of research.

Comment: Aah! it's ok. Next time will post some better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since object1 is a collection, how do you want to print the data.
Assuming that you want to print each object in each line.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < object1.Count; i++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(object1[i].item1, "---", object1[i].Item2)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate through your collection

```
foreach(classname cl in object1)
{
   Console.WriteLine(cl.ToString());
   //or print the property of your class
}
```

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted without posting the reason, there is nothing wrong with my answer

Comment: @user1799320
Sorry, I thought you would see the errors by yourself.
1) Formatting, it's terrible.
2) It won't even compile!
Improve it and I will undo my downvote.

Comment: @Fyodor I didn't have V.Studio or other IDE that time, anyhow I have made the changes

Comment: @user1799320 looks better) ok, also `classname` looks quite confusing... What do you think about `var` ?

Comment: @Fyodor the code he shared in his question has a classname object so that's why I used it in my answer