# how to get data from ObservableCollection C#

Tags: c#, nodes, observablecollection

I use function ObservableCollection in one class.

It is defined public to be reachable in another class also.

```
public ObservableCollection<Node> _nodes;
public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes
{
     get { return _nodes ?? (_nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>()); }
}
```

I want to call this ObservableCollection in another class, how to do it correctly?

I try already with this topic on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198359/how-to-get-data-from-observablecollection-and-display-into-console-application-i), but shows me that Node is empty.

Comment: `Nodes` is not a `static` property, my guess you are trying to access it by using class name, while you need instance of that class. And this reference to instance has to be accessible from other class somehow (means either have it statically accessible, e.g. as a static property of some static class, or, better, pass instance to other class somehow, e.g. as a constructor or method parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your Class A, which contains your "nodes".

To access the nodes from Class B a few things need to happen:

- Class A needs to be a public class that can be instantiated as a member of another class.
- In Class B, you must instantiate a Class A:

  ```
  ClassB {

      _private ClassA instanceOfA;

      public ClassB() {
          istanceOfA = new ClassA();
      }

      private void DoWork()
      {
          foreach(var node in instanceOfA.Nodes)
          {
              // Do Something
          }
      }
  }
  ```

That will give you access to ClassA's public Nodes property.

Another note - it seems like you are using a getter/setter, but in that case your first

```
    public ObservableCollection<Node> _nodes;
```

could be changed to

```
    private ObservableCollection<Node> _nodes;
```

to properly encapsulate it.  Then you could add a setter to your public property (unless it is readonly):

```
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes
    {
        get { return _nodes ?? (_nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>()); }
        set {_nodes = value; }
    }
```

Comment: OK. I have done everything, but when I want data get an error:
"A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WpfApplication1.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an object instance.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

this error occur in "foreach(var nodex in Nodes)"

Comment: How to implement border to Thumb_DragDelta? How to limit "node.X += e.HorizontalChange;"? That Node will not go over this border?

Comment: I'm not sure in this context - it might warrant a new question.